# Excel Macro to Duplicate Sheet, Prompt User to Rename it, and Get Rid of Dropdown Menu

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says, I am looking for a way to create a macro that can duplicate the sheet the user is on, prompt them to rename it, and in addition, get rid of the drop down menu in cell C4 after a button is pressed. How would I go about doing this? I am very new to VBA and macros and I've only done simple ones through the record macro function, so if you could go into detail or post the code that would be super helpful:)

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub rename()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets("Summary").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you have any code that you have recorded to do this? If so, please post it.

Comment: By drop down menu, do you mean the Data Validation setting, drop down control object, ActiveX control?

Comment: Data Validation. I've tried recording but I get an error after the second time because of the overlapping sheet names.

Comment: "after a button is pressed" What button do you mean? Do you want them to select a value from the drop down, and then remove the validation?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Its just a one of those form control buttons.

Comment: Once the button is clicked, I want excel to duplicate and ask the user to rename the file. Then when the new file is created I want the data validation drop down list on cell C4 to be deleted so the user can't mess with it after all is said and done.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand completely. The button starts the macro which prompts the user to give the new file a new name. It will delete the data validation in cell C4. It will then save a copy of the file with this new name that the user previously provided. Can you post the code you have recorded already?

Comment: Yes, but the data validation will only be deleted in the new sheet.

Comment: With some tutorials I've got the duplicating and renaming part, but I still can't get it to delete the data validation Heres what I have:

`Sub rename()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets("Summary").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save the workbook in the same containing folder as the file containing this code. It will use the name provided by the user. If a file already exists with that name, then it will prompt if the user wants to overwrite the old file or not.

```
Sub rename()
    Dim sName As String
    sName = Application.InputBox _
      (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
    Range("C4").Validation.Delete
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sName & ".xlsm", ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```